# Phonegap Build iOS does not validate

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

When we build our app in Phonegap Build for iOS, when we submit it to the app store, we get errors about our icons in the IPA.

We get errors like "ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png for iOS version >= 7.0"

The problem is our config.xml, from all indications is correct.
Here is a link to it if you'd like to see for yourself: https://gist.github.com/marcusds/352afdf47d90d2b13ebb

We are including our icons with:

```
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
```

Is that not correct?
What could we be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Change path of both the icon & splash screen  from `www/res/icon/ios/..`  to  `res/icon/ios/` in your config.xml.

i.e.

```
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60"/>
...
```

to this

```
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60"/>
...
```

Hope it works Now, Good luck.

Comment: OK I've tried that and those icons appear to be added properly. However, Build is adding icon.png to the Info.plist file but not including it correctly. The icon.png file is in www/, same place as index.html and config.xml, by all indications where it should be. But it's not being added to the right location in the IPA, making it fail validation. I've updated my gist with these corrections.